# .htaccess rewriterule ends up as 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to do simple redirects in my .htaccess file, but always end up as 404 pages.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^resume$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Resume.pdf [END,R=301]
RewriteRule ^Resume$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Resume.pdf [END,R=301]
RewriteRule ^resume.pdf$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Resume.pdf [END,R=301]
```

`Redirect 301` does not redirect as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try without DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Resume$ /Resume.pdf [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^resume(\.pdf)?$ /Resume.pdf [L,R=301]
```

Because the DOCUMENT_ROOT is added by default, it must not be 2x